# MySQL: How do I retrieve entries from a table with duplicate values and that satisfy multiple conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following table...

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 4 | 9 |
| 4 | 9 |

I would like to extract all ID numbers that contain the values 7 and 9 (ids 1 and 4 in this case). The problem I am having is that there are duplicate values in the database. I have tried the following self-join:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (SELECT
      id
   FROM
      table_name
   WHERE
      value = 7
   GROUP BY value) AS t1
      JOIN
   (SELECT
      id
   FROM
      table_name
   WHERE
      value = 9
   GROUP BY value) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Which works but I feel has two issues: (1) there is a lot of wasted searching as SQL searches through the table twice*; (2) this code doesn't scale well - what if I wanted to search for the presence of three, four, five, etc. values?

Is there a better approach I could take?

---

*Is this true? I recently began learning SQL and come from a Python background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of query comes up often here.  One approach uses aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM table_name
WHERE value in (7, 9)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 2;
```

Comment: Ahhh so the `DISTINCT` statement return only distinct values! Much better!!

Comment: The strategy is to filter each `id` group of records down to just records having values of 7 or 9.  Then, assert that each group has _two_ distinct values.  If so, then the `id` matches your requirements.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I had not come across the `DISTINCT` statement before

Comment: Is there a way to abstract this even further? So to have the `HAVING` statement read something like `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = len(inputs)` (please excuse the Python syntax)

Comment: Please explain what `len(inputs)` means in the context of your actual SQL table.

Comment: Sorry, actually don't worry about it. This query is for a website, and I'll be able to dynamically change the query based on what the user searchers. Thanks anyway for taking the time out to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is better solved by a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM t
WHERE value IN (7, 9)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 2
```

Comment: Ahhh so the `DISTINCT` statement return only distinct values! Great thanks

Comment: Yes, since you have duplicate `id, value` pairs, you need to count distinct values per id.

Comment: Wonderful! I had not come across the `DISTINCT` statement before!

Comment: The 2 must match the number of items inside the `IN` clause. I guess you would be "building" the `IN` clause in python somehow, from an array or list, then use the sizeof or whatever function to replace the `2`. Other solution is to build a table-like data structure, which is easier in MySQL 8.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to answer my question!